# getting text from html document using HtmlAgilityPack via XPath

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have following html in a file, I am loading this file into an `HTMLDocument` using `HtmlAgilityPack`.

The problem is that I only want to get `Hello World!` using `XPath` and not the inner text.

How do I achieve this?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Hello world!
        <ul>
            <li>
                Welcome to planet!
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath:

```
//ul/li[1]/text()
```

Should select the actual text "Hello World!"

You can then select the value of this node.

In use:

```
string text = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//ul/li[1]/text()").Value;
```

In essence, what this says is navigate to a ul node, select the first li, and then select the text() node.

Comment: @ZainShaikh The HTMLAgilityPack is awesome, isn't it! Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 3):

```
htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul/li").First().FirstChild.InnerText;
```

will return Hello world!